# Edit magento 2 order 'print' layout

Tags: magento2, template, edit-order, magento-2.0.4, directory

So when u go to **My Account -> My Orders**  and click on **view order** and then click **Print Order** then u see a PDF of the order that u just placed. Mine looks all messy :
[image: order print]

So I want to edit this.
Does someone know how to? It's not in the email templates section as far as I can see.

Thanks!

Comment: Just an update of what i ment : I mean that to adjust the order template of magento and use it at the print button. Not the mail but the order itself. The 'bill'